# Chrome Browser and Silverlight

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, silverlight

When I visit [this page](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/tools/tuva/) I get an error stating "Silverlight for your browser is not Officially Supported"

.
[image]

If I click the image on the error page it links to a page indicating Silverlight is installed and ready.

.
[image]

.

Silverlight is indeed installed and working with Chrome on other MS sites like [this one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh124515)

I have cleared cookies, cache, and local storage.

Windows 7 Pro 64bit, latest version of Chrome (non beta)

Does anyone else get this message on that page with Chrome and Silverlight installed.

It works in IE9, I assume it is an evil MS plot.... ;->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no checks for Chrome specifically – [this script](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/tools/tuva/Script/Silverlight.supportedUserAgent.js) rejects **Safari** on Windows, and Chrome has the string "`Safari`" in its [user-agent](http://echo.opera.com/).

Since the site only checks `navigator.userAgent` through JavaScript and not the HTTP header, you can use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aafciojnlamllgpkpdkbamkfgbofhgcj) to spoof the UA.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. I wonder why they only chose that method for this particular site and not the technet site.

Comment: What's the extension? Ironically I'm trying to access the very same page on Feynman and getting the same error.

Good to know there's a fix, but when I click the link for the extension I get "Item not found."

Answer (score -1):

The error says it is not officially supported in your browser, not that it isn't installed.  Evil?  I suspect Chrome may have to decide to support it.

Comment: It is supported, as silverlight loads on other MS pages

Comment: But Microsoft said it wasn't officially supported. It is their  message.

Comment: @Moab: "Works" != "supported".

Comment: just not supported on that particular page, is is on others, I stated this in the original question.